# Oracle date format

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to convert the date  `06/23/2008 4:00:00 PM`  into this format

`MON June 23 16:00:00 EDT 2008`

in oracle.Please give me the sql query to fulfill my requirement of converting the date to the above mentioned format.

Comment: You may want to explain where the 16:00 is coming from, and what you already attempted to do to solve the problem.

Comment: [oracle date formats](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-fmt.html)

Comment: @user1361143 I do realize that 16:00:00 is a time, but the date you're converting from (`06/23/2008`)  has no time, so where does the time come from?

Comment: This date I want to convert 06/23/2008 4:00:00 PM to the above mentioned format

Comment: @user1361143 That makes more sense :) Please update the question with the real data you just mentioned, and in what form you currently have the datetime (varchar? date?)

Comment: why is there `(mm/dd/yyyy)` in the string? is it literally there?

Comment: MM/DD/YYYY IS ONLY A HINT FOR DATE FORMAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under PostgreSQL it would be as follows (and it should work fine under Oracle):

```
select to_char(DATE '06/23/2008', 'DY FMMONTH dd 16:00:00 "EDT" yyyy');
```

Produces:

```
MON JUNE 23 16:00:00 EDT 2008
```

The 'FM' before 'MONTH' removes space padding (added to make all months take up the same length).

Double quoting EDT ensures that it is not interpreted as part of the to_char date formatting.

Updated to include time:

```
select to_char(TIMESTAMP '06/23/2008 4:00:00 PM', 'DY FMMONTH dd HH24:MI:SS "EDT" yyyy');
```

Produces:

```
MON JUNE 23 16:00:00 EDT 2008
```

Comment: Sorry, but test query "select to_char(SysDate, 'DY FMMONTH dd 16:00:00 "EDT" yyyy') from Dual" doesn't work on Oracle (ORA-01821 error)

Comment: select to_char(SYSDATE,'DY FMMONTH dd HH:MI:SS "EDT" yyyy') from dual; IS WORKING THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `(mm/dd/yyyy)` bit is not actually part of the string:

```
select to_char(to_date(
        '06/23/2008 4:00:00 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM')
       ,'DY fmMonth DD fmHH24:MI:SS "EDT" YYYY'
       ) from dual;

MON June 23 16:00:00 EDT 2008
```

You don't specify what to show for day-of-month and hours less than 10 - e.g. should 5 June be shown as `June 05` or `June 5`? I've assumed the latter.